# Snap Scroll React Overflow

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have 3 sections and i want the scroll to snap to the next section which works fine but i get overflow at the very bottom and very top. when i do overflow hidden the overflow fixes but the snapping stops working and vice versa

```
// App.js

import React from 'react';
import Section from "./components/sectionOne/sectionOne";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <main className="appContainer">
      <Section color='grey' />
      <Section color='white' />
      <Section color='darkgrey' />
    </main>
  );
};

export default App;

/* App.css */

.appContainer {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; /* Apply scroll snap type to main element */
  }
  
  section {
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    scroll-snap-stop: always;
  }
  .sectionOne{
    background-color: lightgrey;
    height: 100%;
}
```

i tried to do overflow y hidden and scroll as well as overflow hidden in the html tag or body tag or the section tag. ive run out of ideas